# Is there any way to upload a screenshot from an iPad to this site (or other StackExchange sites)?

Tags: ipad

So I capture a screenshot with my handy "[HOME]-[POWER]" combo, and draw freehand arrows on it in Adobe Ideas (because I like their line smoothing) to highlight my problem, but:

How do I upload this picture to Ask Different from the iPad?

Answer (score 11):

Use Dropbox to upload it, then copy the link to the clipboard and paste it in your answer using the Markdown syntax: `![alt text](url)`

Answer (score 4):

Dropbox is a good idea, but since you are using Adobe Ideas, which has an "email photo" link, you could just use the Email Upload features of any photo sharing site (eg. [Flickr email upload link](http://www.flickr.com/account/uploadbyemail/), twitpic, etc.), and then copy the link from the browser.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you can't do so directly (darn it) so you'd have to do it indirectly. You can either sync it to a computer and then use that computer to ask your question, or upload it to a Web site and then manually use that URL for the image (via either Markdown or HTML).

Comment: appreciate the thoughts, but if I'm syncing, I'm at a computer, and have other options.  How would I upload it to a website from my ipad?  That sounds like just what I can't do on *these* websites?

Comment: You can't do it on the SE sites (so far as I can figure out), but there are apps that let you (for instance) upload images to Flickr. And once it's on Flickr, you can manually create a image tag here that references the image there.

Comment: Jaydles, you can't upload files from Safari on *any* site. The app-centric suggestions that others made are the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I use photobucket, it's free has quite good features, and the iPhone app (not sure if there's a specific iPad app) works very simply, choose the photo, press upload, get the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StackAsk to upload images from your Photo library and camera roll into new questions you ask. It works both on iPad and iPhone.

You can get it free on the app store, theres a link in this post: [StackAsk on StackApps](https://stackapps.com/q/2633/938)

(disclosure: I made the app)