# What version of iOS enabled Safari / native camera roll integration?

Tags: ios, safari, photos

On macOS, there are music [photo and video pickers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10652/) integrated into the OS via standard file open API. [Initially](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/15209/5472), iOS [lacked this for Safari](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/2914/5472) and third party apps. Web sites and Safari had use third party apps or custom JavaScript code to allow this.

Which version of iOS enabled this natively?

Comment: I‘m sure you know what you are doing, but which practical problem are you trying to solve here? :-)

Comment: @nohillside A canonical question so we can close all the old questions that say this isn't possible with a practical answer / summary. Also, people pull old devices that can no longer update, so we'll continue to get these questions until devices finally stop working : - ) (also, this is being redesigned for Big Sur / iOS 14 so there will be three designs of this in play soon with enhanced privacy controls - getting ahead of that curve with a canonical place to document Apple's iterations here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 6

> Safari
>
> - Support for photo upload via Camera Roll to web forms with `<input type="file">` elements.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#iOS_6